# Order by date a select query on UNION ALL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, union-all

I have little problem with my MySql query:
I have two tables:

Table **timeline**

```
id | date      |  text
1    2013-10-13   Hello
```

Table **reps**

```
id | date      | text
1   2013-10-12   Its me again
1   2013-10-11   What?
1   2013-10-10   Lorem ipsum
```

What i am doing is  `UNION ALL` timeline and reps.First row should always be the row from timeline(it's always one row) and then all rows from reps table but in `DESC` order.

My query is the following one(which work ok except from order by)

```
select id,date,text from timeline UNION ALL select * from reps order by date desc
```

Think something like a comment (sits on top) with replies on the comment in desc order,newest first.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put the UNION in a subquery:

```
SELECT id, date, text
FROM (SELECT id, date, text, 1 AS priority
      FROM timeline
      UNION ALL
      SELECT *, 2 AS priority
      FROM reps) u
ORDER BY priority, date DESC
```

Comment: you have to order by id first

Comment: @Jonysuise Huh? Why so?

Comment: I don't see any mention of that in the question. He said timeline just  has one row. I suspect his actual query has `where id = ...` in both subqueries, so he's not showing all IDs.

Comment: assuming the id of the reps table is the fk of the id of the timelines table... :(

Comment: Worked like charm! Thank to all the other too!

Answer (score 1):

your query is right , you just close second query by () like that: and it will order just the second query . without () it will order the two queries.

```
   select id,date,text from timeline 
    UNION all
  (select * from reps order by date desc)
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but will `UNION ALL` guarantee that the result on the left hand side stays before all results on the right hand side?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson if you select it first then it comes first .

Answer (score 0):

Make a Unix_timestamp from the date value and order by its value.

```
 SELECT -1 as 'id' , 99999999999999 as 'sortalias' , now() as 'datum||date'
 UNION
 ( SELECT
      id
      ,unix_timestamp(datum) as 'sortalias'
      ,datum as 'datum||date'
      FROM kunde
 )
 order by sortalias desc
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select id,date,text from (
    select id,1 poid,date,text
    from timeline
    union all
    select id,2 poid,date,text
    from reps
) t
order by t.id asc,t.poid asc,t.date desc
```